# Best way to build a library of Rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a few really common things I do with Rakefiles and I'd like to build a library of common tasks that I can inherit into my Rakefile.  What's the easiest/best way to do this?

Comment: I would consider a gem.

Comment: Right, I guess my question really is in the gem when I define a "task" which is a ruby method how can I inherit that into the namespace?  and if there is an include "rake" of some sort what will happen when I run that in the regular rake space after writing that code in my gem?  Two includes?  the one from the rake binary and my library?

Comment: It might make sense to post an example of what you actually try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In you project folder you could make a file and name it Rakefile. Here is a sample file `Rakefile` that you could use to load rake tasks if you want to get the files one at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/junk.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

load File.expand_path('../lib/tasks/foo.rake', __FILE__)
load File.expand_path('../lib/tasks/bar.rake', __FILE__)

desc "Execute specific rake tasks"
task :execute_specific do 
  puts "I'm executing specific"
end
```

If you wanted to get everything in a folder use this:

```
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

Use `rake -T` to see all the tasks that have been loaded.

Comment: `Dir['lib/tasks/*.rake'].each(&method(:load))` is equivalent. If you're only calling a single method, you can avoid writing an explicit loop, and this will typically be (negligibly) faster and more concise. N.B.: this comment offers an alternative, but not a recommendation.